# Form.IO: Use the Select component static search as the input to dynamically update the list

Tags: select, drop-down-menu, formio

If I have a Form.IO Select component, pulling data from a URL, is there a way to use the static search as the input for further paginated debounce?

Essentially I would like a single field, which as you type uses the search to pull data from the URL, and update the select list.

Any help would be awesome!